# Angular Load data OnScroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Just need some help, Im stuck and  don't have an idea how to implement this append in Angular. I want to append a new data when the user scroll and the scrollbar hits the bottom. here is my code.

note DataModel.getAllData access the api with paging parameters.

I stuck on how to add new elements during onScroll. here is what i am trying to achieve on scroll I want to use the list_of_data.html. put all the new data in list_of_data. get the final output then append it on data_list.

**directive**

```
app.directive('scroll', function() {
  console.log('scroll directive');
  return function(scope, elm, attr) {
    var raw = elm[0];
    elm.bind('scroll', function() {
      if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight - 20) {
        scope.$apply(attr.scroll);
      }
    });
  };
});
```

**main.html**

```
 <div class="container" scroll="onScroll()">
    <div id="data_list" data-ng-init="getData()" >
    <div  ng-include src="data_uri"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**list_of_data.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="mydata in list_of_data">
      <div>mydata.name</div>
      <div>mydata.description</div>     
</div>
```

**controller**

```
  var next;
$scope.onScroll = function()
{ 
  if(next != null || next != "undefined"){
     DataModel.getAllData(user_info,next)
  .then(function (data) {
    $scope.list_of_data = data;
    next = data.next;
  }, function (error) {
    console.log("error"); 
  });
  }
} 

$scope.getData = function(){
  $scope.data_uri= 'views/list/list_of_data.html';
  DataModel.getAllData(user_info)
  .then(function (data) {
    $scope.list_of_data = data;
    next = data.next;
  }, function (error) {
    console.log("error"); 
  });
}
```

//EDIT I tried something like this. but it just overrides the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like :

```
$scope.onScroll = function()
{ 
  DataModel.getNextData().then(function(results){
      $scope.list_of_data.push(results);
  });

}
```

Assuming that you have a specific API function to get the next results.

Comment: oh. thanks for the idea. so since im appending new data in list_of_data, does this the ng-repeat add up? like first is 20, next result is 20 then push so it will be 40. does the ng-repeat loop again in 40 data?

Comment: ng-repeat is resfreshed with the help of the binding. Each time you update your JS list, the angular digest cycle runs and ng-repeat re-run on updated data. That the cool thing of angular :)

Comment: nah. nevermind. nobody is gonna scroll a 1000 topics

Comment: As the angular team said, you should consider that having more than 2000 binded models starts to freeze your app. Have only this number in mind :)